# CentOS 7 ip masquerade for internet access

Tags: firewall, masquerade

My CentOS XYZ has two network interfaces:

```
iface1 136.136.10.10 is connected to gateway 136.136.10.1
iface2 192.168.10.1 is connected to private network
```

XYZ can access the internet through gateway 136.136.10.1 which is connected to the internet.

My other CentOS ABC has one network interface iface (192.168.10.2) that is internal. Now, how do I connect ABC to the internet?

I tried to add masquerade but with no avail:

On XYZ:

```
 # iptables --flush
 # iptables --table nat --flush
 # iptables --delete-chain
 # iptables --table nat --delete-chain
 # iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface iface1 -j MASQUERADE
 # iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface iface2 -j ACCEPT
 # echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
 # systemctl restart network.service
```

on ABC:

```
 added 192.168.10.1 as gateway
```

Thanks,

Comment: Probably when you restart the network.service the network settings go back to their original settings and /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward reverts to 0. Do you have network without restarting the service? Also if you use firewalld you only need: firewall-cmd --add-masquerade --zone=<zone of iface1>

Comment: As nkms mentioned, in order to save ip_forward configuration, add the following into `/etc/sysctl.conf`: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: i tried both guys and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I fixed another problem in one of my interfaces, the problem is solved. Bottom line: the instructions I followed are valid and can be used to connect ABC to the internet.